# Setting up the testing environment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I would like to know if it is possible to set up the testing environment in laravel with a database that is not existing in your pc, for example i have mysql datbase, and i want to set up the test to be in mysqllite is that possible if not, how can i set up the testing environment in laravel with mysql database ?

when i try this :

```
'sqlite_testing' => [
     'driver' => 'sqlite',
     'database' => ":memory:",
],
```

i get this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (Connection: sqlite_testing, SQL: select * from sqlite_master where 
type = 'table' and name = migrations)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'mysql_testing' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'database' => "testing_db",
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        ],
```

i want to the database.php file and set up the mysql environment like this and created a database called testing_db in phpmyadmin and it worked, turns out you can't run a test on databse that is not in your local environment

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you came to this conclusion, but there does have ways to use another testing only database when executing unit tests, and you don't have to create a new driver config for testing.

Creating a `.env.testing` in your project root, it also allow you using different host, username or database for testing, it's simple just as you set a normal `.env`.

```
# In .env.testing file
... 
DB_CONNECTION=mysql  # Also allow you to using different driver for testing.
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb   # You can set testing database here.
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
...
```

Laravel already set done PHPUnit xml config, it will trying to load `.env.testing` when running test, if there is no `.env.tesing`, it will load the `.env`, you can find more details from here：https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#the-env-testing-environment-file

Comment: ohhh i'm going to try this solution too. Thank you